# "uses" section equivalent in C++ Builder

Tags: c++builder

I'm using C++ Builder 2009 and I'm trying to get my `Korzh's Localizer` component to to process my `Fast Reports` for translation. The component properly translates the rest of my program.

In order to translate the `Fast Reports`, there is an extra step. In the directions, there is reference to using `LocFRProcs` by putting the unit name in the `uses` section. Unforcunately my delphi knowledge is low, so I don't know the equivalent of this in C++... my guess is that I need to do some sort of include... but I'm not sure how to do it with the .pas file.

### Some screen shots for clarification

The search for `LocFRProcs`:

[image]

The directory that has `LocFRProcs.pas`:

[image]

The Korzh instructionsfor adding `LocFRProcs` into the uses section:

[image]

**Update 2:**

1. Open the localizer12 project file.
2. Right click on the project and go to options
3. Click on Linking
4. Change "Linker Output" to "Generate all C++ Builder files (including package libs)"
5. Click OK
6. Right click on project and select build.
7. I thought this would generate a LocFRProcs.hpp or LocFRProcs.h file but didn't.

Screenshot of directory after build with generate all:
[image]

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/DCC32.EXE%2C_the_Delphi_Command_Line_Compiler) will help. It's for XE3, but the info on `dcc32.exe` would still apply to Builder 2009 files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ equivalent of the `uses` clause is indeed `#include` statements.  You don't include the .pas file, you include its C++ .hpp header file instead, eg:

Delphi:

```
uses
   ..., LocFRProcs;
```

C++:

```
...
#include <LocFRProcs.hpp>
```

If you do not have a LocFRProcs.hpp file, you will have to compile LocFRProcs.pas first.  C++Builder has a command-line Delphi compiler, if you do not have the Delphi personality installed in the IDE and/or if the component package does not include a C++ project for compiling the .pas file(s) in the C++ IDE  Either way, when compiling a .pas file, you can configure the Delphi compiler to output C++ support files (.hpp, .obj, .lib, etc).

Comment: Thanks Remy. I put my steps down, under Update 2, as far as what I did to try to generate the .hpp output. My steps did not work for that .pas file. Anything you see I'm missing or any other thoughts?

Comment: The file does not seem to be part of the project, which explains why it did not generate a header file... will look at in more detail and should hopefully figure it out. Thx.

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. I just added the .pas file to the project then rebuilt and it generated the .hpp file I needed, so I was then able to do the include statement. thanks Remy!

Answer (score 0):

Remy's answer is certainly correct, but since this question comes up at the top in a Google Search for the "uses" section equivalent in C++ Builder (from the title), I would just point out that, when a primarily-Delphi library says to include a unit in the "uses" section, that can mean one or more of:

```
(1) #include statements 
(2) .lib file included in the Project 
(3) #pragma link
```

This came up with the DevExpress VCL dxRichEditControl, for which the documentation regarding adding new file save formats says, "add the dxRichEdit.OpenXML, dxRichEdit.Doc, and/or dxRichEdit.Html unit(s) to the uses clause"

For that library, that means:

(1) Add the #include statements

```
#include "dxRichEdit.OpenXML.hpp"
#include "dxRichEdit.Html.hpp"
#include "dxRichEdit.Doc.hpp"
```

(2) Add the .lib files to the project

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress\VCL\Library\RS26\dxRichEditControlDocFormatRS26.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress\VCL\Library\RS26\dxRichEditControlHtmlFormatRS26.lib
C:\Program Files (x86)\DevExpress\VCL\Library\RS26\dxRichEditControlOpenXMLFormatRS26.lib
```

(3) No need for the #pragma link, because those statements are generated and included in the .hpp files